# How to find the templates which is responsible for showing at the front in magento website

Tags: magento

I am new to magento. Is there any easy way to find out which page is responsible for the frontend page? I want to edit a search reasult page but could not found which template or .phtml or .php pages are rendering to show the search reasult page at front. Thanks

I just want to place currency format and put the strike in the RRP, showing the Sale Price next to it.

Comment: Tags are something that help Subject Matters Experts find your question if you don't add relevant tags to your question there won't be much chance of any relevant people looking at it. See: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)